# How to typeguard ChildNode? Or use ChildNode methods with Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, dom

I want to use `ChildNode` methods. If for ex. I typeguard it:

```
const node = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startContainer;

if (this.isChildNode(node)) {
  this.node.replaceWith(...);
}

isChildNode(node: Node): node is ChildNode {
  return 'replaceWith' in node;
}
```

Throws error:

> A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
>   Type 'ChildNode' is not assignable to type 'Node'. Property 'baseURI'
>   is missing in type 'ChildNode'

If I just cast it:

```
const node = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startContainer;
(node as ChildNode).replaceWith(...nodes)
```

Throws error:

> Type 'Node' cannot be converted to type 'ChildNode'
>
> Property 'remove' is missing in type 'Node'

Only `any` compiles the app:

```
(node as any).replaceWith(...nodes)
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7hljly)

What confuses me is that [ChldNode docs in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode) states, that ChildNode does not inherit any properties or methods. So how does it `extends Node` in Typescript...?

Comment: ChildNode does not extend Node. On the MDN you mention `There are no inherited methods.`  So what makes you think it extends in typescript?

Comment: This - `interface ChildNode extends Node`. And to clarify - my code runs, only Typescript fails to compile

Comment: I see it in the specs indeed.. Somehow it works for me locally. Your exact code. Perhaps you can try to update to the latest version of angular and with it, typescript?

Comment: Upgrading Angular is not an option (current version 6), though I suspect it wouldnt help because in Stackblitz demo I posted here, uses Angular 8 and Typrscript ~3.1.1. And you can see there these Typescript errors

Comment: locally I use a higher typescript version though. You can find some issues related to this here https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27453 and https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28551

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why noone suggested to cast after typeguard check? Its completaly safe to do there and it compiles...

```
const node = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startContainer;

if (this.isChildNode(node)) {
  (this.node as ChildNode).replaceWith(...nodes)
}

isChildNode(node: Node): node is ChildNode {
  return 'replaceWith' in node;
}
```